# GET Call: An item with the same key has already been added. Key: Id

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to use EF Core to call a stored procedure in a SQL Server db. The db server is hosted using Docker. The problem is when I make a GET call to the controller to hit the service, it stalls for a little while and then I get this error...

> ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added. Key: Id

Here's my code:

**Models**

```
public interface IGiftList
{
   int Id { get; set; }
   string Occasion { get; set; }
   int UserId { get; set; }
   string Alias { get; set; }
   bool AnotherRecipient { get; set; }
   string RecipientName { get; set; }
   int RecipientAddressId { get; set; }
}

public class GiftList : IGiftList
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Occasion { get; set; }
   public int UserId { get; set; }
   public string Alias { get; set; }
   public bool AnotherRecipient { get; set; }
   public string RecipientName { get; set; }
   public int RecipientAddressId { get; set; }
   public List<Gift> Items { get; set;}
}
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpGet, Route("lists")]
public List<GiftList> GetUserLists([FromQuery] int userId)
{
   var lists = _giftService.GetUserLists(userId).Select(l => (GiftList)l).ToList();
   return lists;
}
```

**Service**

```
public List<IGiftList> GetUserLists(int userId)
{
   var items = this.giftContext.Lists.FromSqlRaw($"EXECUTE dbo.GetUserLists @UserId={userId}").ToList<IGiftList>(); <--Exception gets raised here.
   return items;
}
```

**Stored Procedure**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GetUserLists 
(
    @UserId INT
)
AS
DECLARE @ListId INT

SET @ListId = (SELECT TOP (1) Id FROM Lists WHERE UserId = @UserId);

SELECT 
    L.Id,
    O.Title,
    U.Id,
    L.Alias,
    L.AnotherRecipient,
    L.RecipientName,
    L.RecipientAddressId
FROM Lists AS L
JOIN Occasions AS O
    ON O.Id = L.OccasionId
JOIN Users AS U
    ON U.Id = L.UserId
WHERE
    L.UserId = @UserId
```

Any idea why I might be getting this error?

Comment: What does the raw data look like?

Comment: Its beacuse of these two  `L.Id,`  `U.Id,` which treated as Id so use Alias  `U.Id  AS UserId`  to to make them diffrent name, will resolve the problem.

Comment: Unrelated to your error, your procedure doesn't need to hit `Lists` twice and is missing an ordering criteria for the `top(1)` - you are getting 1 random Id

Comment: Alter the strore procedure's this field  `U.Id AS UserId,`

Comment: @Stu Good point. The SP isn't finished. I was trying to get accomplish this task in small parts. Now that I have it working (thanks to Md Farid), now I can move on to it. I was getting the list Id because I will be making a second call to the actual items so that this SP will return two data sets. Not sure how to do this in ef core so if anyone has an idea or can point me in the right direction then I'd be eternally greatful :)

Comment: I'm glad to assist you on this. Additionally regarding your new expectations would you kindly post a new question with what you are trying to achieve and the challenges you have encountered, so that we could assist on that as well it will make this thread unique. Hope you got my point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because of your `Store Procedure's` two fields which are  `L.Id` and `U.Id` those are treating as `Id` but when it comes to bind with your model property which are `Id` and `UserId` the compliler gets problem to mapping with two. So the best way is to handle this using SQL Alias `AS`.

`U.Id AS UserId` would resolve your problem.

> ***Note:*** If the primary keys in the select query's are same remember to make them seperate by uisng `AS` other than it will
> mappped as same key.

Comment: Ah! It's soooo obvious now. Thank you. I'll implement this fix and let you know how it goes. Thank you.

Comment: No worries. Let us know your update if it resolve the problem accordingly. I hope it would.